# Floating divs do not expand container

Tags: html, css, overflow

I expect my question has already been answered numerous times but I couldn't find it.
I'm trying to create 2 divs which are next to each other within a container. However as soon as I add content, they overflow. I've included a JSFiddle but for some reason my 2 divs are already appearing outside of the container - it doesn't on my local version. I'd like the div which the content is in to expand as well as the container. Hope I've explained it ok.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaL5jpqv/)

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

body {
    background-color:#C0D498;
}

#page-wrap {
    background-color:#FFF;
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
    width:175px;
    height:auto;
}

.banner {
    width:755px;
    height:175px;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image:url('images/banner.png');
}

.contentWrap {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.contentMain {
    width:70%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
}
.contentSub {
    width:30%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your html with this:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
    <div class="banner"></div>         
    <div class="contentWrap">
                <div class="contentMain">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac semper mauris. Maecenas orci dui, auctor ac auctor eu, pretium et mi. Donec interdum diam in est euismod gravida. Curabitur ligula tortor, bibendum nec odio maximus, efficitur lobortis mauris. Vestibulum in est rutrum, imperdiet turpis quis, elementum massa. Sed quis odio ut urna porttitor lobortis. Vivamus feugiat accumsan porttitor. Quisque sed ligula ac neque faucibus tristique. Suspendisse molestie eleifend purus vitae maximus. Proin posuere ante ut velit condimentum aliquam. Nullam pellentesque, mi rhoncus sagittis efficitur, libero ante scelerisque turpis, quis cursus dui libero eget dui. Suspendisse fringilla ut massa at aliquam. Praesent ut tempus erat, nec euismod ligula. Aliquam dui ex, viverra id commodo a, cursus sed sem. Praesent vel egestas nisl.</div>
                <div class="contentSub">g</div>
            </div>
    <div style="clear:both; float:none;"></div>
        </div>
```

The important part is this: `<div style="clear:both; float:none;"></div>`

and of course you can do it like this (recommended)

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

and CSS

```
.clear{clear:both; float:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

.contentWrap { overflow: hidden; }

only this!

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you want to float your banner
http://jsfiddle.net/flocko/fhrpghjb/

```
.contentWrap {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

as a rule of thumb: every element you float - you should clear in the parent element.

a clearfix class could help you on your way: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/